# Nothing shows up when I try to load a python file

Tags: python, powershell

Im reading the ebook "Learn python the hard way" On example 25, I coded everything correct but when I try to load the file in powershell, nothing comes up. No errors or anything but the file dosent load up. It also said load it in python after you found all errors but it dosent load there either. What could my error possibly be? Why wont it load?

Here is my code:

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Comment: If this is all your code, you aren't executing any functions!

Comment: care to explain? this is the exact code he typed and his showed up. sooo

Comment: Who's he? And what did he type? And what showed up?

Comment: he typed what i did and he got

Comment: ugh its too long but basically its what the other answer got

Comment: This is silly. The user needs to learn the difference between declaring a function and executing it. It's the basis of any programming language.

Comment: Hence why im learning python buddy. Thats why I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe start with something simple, like outputting hello world.

Comment: Im not starting. this chapter is particularly hard. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html

Comment: It seems like you didn't even read the exercise in the link you posted. Read it completely, and follow the steps he does in the shell, and you should see the expected output.

Comment: If i didnt read it fully I would not have asked it. Its not working.

Answer (score 1):

The file is imported into the shell in the example and run like below and importantly run from a `python shell` not `powershell`:

```
>>> import ex25 # import file
>>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait." # create variable sentence
>>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence) # create variable words
>>> words # input 
['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.'] # output
>>> sorted_words = ex25.sort_words(words) # create `sorted_words` variable using `sort_words` method
>>> sorted_words # 
['All', 'come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.', 'who'] # output
>>> ex25.print_first_word(words) # call `print_first_word` method
All  # output
>>> ex25.print_last_word(words) # call `print_last_word` method
wait. # output
```

open a shell in the same directory you have saved the py file and run the commands above,
don't enter  `>>>`, that is just part of the shell output from the example

If you want output when you run the script from powershell with `python ex25.py` use `if __name__== "__main__"`:

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
if __name__=="__main__":
      sentence = "All good things come to those who wait." # create variable sentence
      words = break_words(sentence) # create variable words
      print words # input

      sorted_words = sort_words(words) # create `sorted_words` variable using `sort_words` method
      print sorted_words #

      print_first_word(words) # call `print_first_word` method

      print_last_word(words) # call `print_last_word` method
```

Comment: didnt work. I have to code in exactly as typed but nothing shows up.

Comment: you are in a python shell yes?

Comment: what happens when you input `import ex25`?

Comment: nothing. its like you just press enter and it just goes in like its got nothing in the file.

Comment: that is what is supposed to happen. what happens when you run the lines of code , `sentence = "All good things come to those who wait." ` then `words = ex25.break_words(sentence)`?

Comment: This is silly. The user needs to learn the difference between declaring a function and executing it. It's the basis of any programming language.

Comment: @AshishKasturia, I think the OP needs to learn the difference between importing a module then running the functions in a shell and actually running it as a script.

Comment: you did not answer the question. What happens when you run the two commands after `import ex_25`?

Comment: nothing happens at all when i do ex25.py or import ex25

Comment: So you ran `sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."` then `words = ex25.break_words(sentence)`  and `words` and you saw no output?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a bunch of functions in the file. What output were you expecting to see?

You need to execute one of those procedures if you want to see anything. For example...

```
break_words('foo bar')
```

Comment: Okay, here's the thing. In your file you declared a bunch of functions. But you haven't used those functions anywhere. That's why you didn't see any output. Try adding this to the end of the file...

`print break_words('foo bar')`.

Then save the file and load it again.

Comment: only thing that shows up is foo bar, what do i need to do to make them all work?

Comment: Call them all after you've declared them.

Comment: I did what he did. Look at the page. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html

Comment: Did you save your file as ex25.py? And did you type in everything after the `>>>` on that webpage?

Comment: I got the output exactly like on that URL. And also, you really need to go through the python tutorial on python's website and understand fundamental concepts before you can proceed.

Comment: What did you load? Because I guarantee I did the same thing as you. I type in ex25.py and it wont load. I type python and go to import ex25 and nothing loads.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the book for a 'main' program which goes with the functions. It may be on another page or so. You probably only loaded the functions.